# Unable to Create Correct Hierarchy of Tasks while Exporting to MS Project using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-project

I am trying export grid data to ms project using vb.net. I am having these data in grid

```
ID                   Task
1            Task1
1.1              Task2
1.1.1                 Task2.1
1.1.1.2               Task2.2
1.2              Task3
1.2.1                 Task3.1
```

but after Exporting it to MS Project I am getting the output as

```
Task Name           OutlineLevel        OutlineNumber
 Task1                     1                       1
     Task2                 2                       1.1        
     Task3                 2                       1.2

        Task2.2            3                       1.2.1
        Task2.3            3                       1.2.2
        Task3.1            3                       1.2.3
```

Incorrect Outline Numbers are generated although task added sequentially. And it also adds a blank row in between.
I have used the following code

```
 Private Sub ubtnExport_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ubtnExport.Click
    Try
        Dim ProjectApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.ApplicationClass()
        ProjectApp.AppMaximize()

        ProjectApp.FileNew(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
        Dim Project As Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Project = ProjectApp.ActiveProject


        Dim Task As Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Task
        dtTempWBSDetail = CType(Grid.DataSource, DataTable)

        For Each dtRow As DataRow In dtTempWBSDetail.Select("Hlevel=1")
            Task = Project.Tasks.Add(dtRow("Particular"), dtRow("UniqueNo"))

            Task.OutlineLevel = dtRow("HLevel")
            Task.Text1 = dtRow("Id")

            If Val(Convert.ToString(dtRow("% Complete"))) <> 0 Then
                Task.PercentComplete = dtRow("% Complete")
            End If

            CreateSubTask(dtRow("WBSNo"), dtRow("WBSTaskNo"), dtRow("HLevel"), Task, Project)
        Next

        Project = Nothing
        ProjectApp = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
 Sub CreateSubTask(ByVal WBSNo As Integer, ByVal WBSTaskNo As Integer, ByVal HLevel As Short, ByVal Task As Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Task, ByVal Project As Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Project) 
    For Each dtRow As DataRow In dtTempWBSDetail.Select("IsNull(WBSParentTaskNo,0) =" & WBSTaskNo.ToString & " and IsNull(WBSParentNo,0)=" & WBSNo)
        Dim ChildTask As Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Task = Task.OutlineChildren.Add(dtRow("Particular"), dtRow("UniqueNo"))


        ChildTask.OutlineLevel = dtRow("HLevel")
        ChildTask.Text1 = dtRow("Id")


        If Val(Convert.ToString(dtRow("% Complete"))) <> 0 Then
            ChildTask.PercentComplete = dtRow("% Complete")
        End If

        CreateSubTask(dtRow("WBSNo"), dtRow("WBSTaskNo"), dtRow("HLevel"), ChildTask, Project)
    Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: Show us the code that you use to export the data. Otherwise how do you imagine us to know what you are doing wrong?

Comment: I have added the code. Plz do suggest whats wrong with this code.

Comment: You should make `CreateSubTask` recursive and query for a HLevel respsctive to the recursion depth.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly There was a problem in Task.add() Method. 
The First argument is Name of task and 
the second argument is The position of the task in its containing collection.
The second argument i supplied was wrong and the blank row generated was due to it only.

Secondly to create outline structure of task only Task.OutlineLevel is not sufficient as it specify the level of task in hierarchy. Task.outlineNumber exactly specify the task's position in hierarchy but it is a read only property. 
so I used Task.OutlineIndent() And Task.OutlineOutdent() method.

I used the code
     Dim iTaskIndex As Integer
     Dim PrevOutlineLevel As Short

```
 Private Sub ubtnExport_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ubtnExport.Click
    Try

        Dim ProjectApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.ApplicationClass()
        ProjectApp.AppMaximize()

        ProjectApp.FileNew(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
        Dim Project As Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Project = ProjectApp.ActiveProject

        Dim Task As Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Task
        dtTempWBSDetail = CType(ugdTaskDetails.DataSource, DataTable)

        iTaskIndex = 1
        PrevOutlineLevel = 1

        For Each dtRow As DataRow In ugdTaskDetails.Rows
            If Convert.ToString(dtRow("Id")) <> "" Then

                AddTaskToProject(Project, dtRow)
                iTaskIndex = iTaskIndex + 1
            End If
        Next
        Project = Nothing
        ProjectApp = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
Sub AddTaskToProject(ByVal Project As Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Project, ByVal dtRow As Datarow)
    Dim Task As Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Task
    Task = Project.Tasks.Add(dtRow("Particular"), iTaskIndex) 

    If Val(Convert.ToString(dtRow("HLevel"))) - PrevOutlineLevel > 0 Then
        Task.OutlineIndent()
    Else
        For Ol As Short = 1 To PrevOutlineLevel - Val(Convert.ToString(dtRow("HLevel")))
            Task.OutlineOutdent()
        Next
    End If

    Task.Text1 = dtRow("Id")


    If Val(Convert.ToString(dtRow("% Complete"))) <> 0 Then
         Task.PercentComplete = dtRow("% Complete")
    End If


    PrevOutlineLevel = dtRow("HLevel")
End Sub
```